# Publish experimental data

Tags: data, online-publication

I recently submitted a paper to a conference together with some colleagues. The paper was accepted with some helpful review comments. Specifically, one reviewer suggested to make the underlying data available to the public. In my case the data is comprised of a network derived from openstreetmap data.

My questions are the following:

- Where can I persistently store the data (totaling ~60 MB)?
- Can I get a DOI for the data itself?
- What about copyright notices (attribution seems necessary)?

Comment: How about https://www.researchgate.net/ ?

Comment: I’m a fan of the Dryad repository.

Comment: Do any of the coauthors work at a "Google campus"?  You could put on Google Drive and change sharing settings to "Anyone with the link" which provides a usable hyperlink. 

Have you thought of posting to Kaggle?   (kaggle.com)

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of data repositories: generic and subject specific. Check what repository may be used by your discipline, and see if it meets your requirements. re3data.org allows you to find an appropriate repository to access and deposit research data (https://www.re3data.org/). There is also a number of generic repositories: Dryad (as mentioned in a previous comment), Figshare, etc. Often they will assign DOIs for your content and will allow you to pick an appropriate license. I would advocate for CC-BY, CC0, or CC-BY-SA. Those are least restrictive and allow others to build on your work.