# What is the best place to make Excel files publicly accessible?

Tags: paper-submission, arxiv, latex

As part of the e-publication of a paper on the arXiv server, I am considering storing Excel files associated with the paper on GitHub. arXiv does not allow PDF submissions to have attached files (Excel or other). The Excel files should be publicly available to anyone reading (and reviewing) the paper on arXiv. In that way I could submit the paper to arXiv as a PDF and list the link to the Excel files on GitHub as linked references. That would avoid going through the LaTex learning curve needed for submitting the paper in LaTex format.

Questions:

1. Is GitHub the best place to make these Excel files permanently publicly available as a permanent and unchanged internet link?
2. Are here downsides in distributing the files over two locations (arXiv and GitHub) compared to keeping them all on the arXiv server?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Just remember, that it might seem like GitHub will be around forever (and indeed is being [archived](https://archiveprogram.github.com/approach/)), but Microsoft could just as easily decide to dump it tomorrow.

Comment: See also: [Publish experimental data](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/115053/publish-experimental-data) or [Cite Repository in manuscript: GitHub link "https://github.com/User/Code" VS zenodo link](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/148682/cite-repository-in-manuscript-github-link-https-github-com-user-code-vs-zen)

Comment: Based on the answers thus far, the Zenodo depository appears to be a better choice than GitHub. Thanks Snijderfrey!